# 'drive perfetch count' in hdparm

Tags: hard-drive, hdparm

What's the **drive perfetch count** in hdparm and what does it do? Should I change it?
I would like to have both: Information for HDDs and SSDs

```
hdparm -h

 -P   Set drive prefetch count
```

Comment: Apparently it's something that was long dropped from official ATA/ACS standard. And even in (old) drives that implement it, the actual implementations were probably vendor-specific.

Comment: But what is it, what does it change?

Comment: (if it would) @TomYan